# What mean *@param array|string|\Closure $middleware

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, closures, middleware

I'm in Laravel 5.6, `Controller.php` abstract class with `Illuminate\Routing` namespace and I would like know what kind of parameter is specified in line 19 to declared method in line 23.

I know what closure and middleware are but I don't know what this line means.

```
16 /*
17 * Register middleware on the controller.
18 *
19 * @param  array|string|\Closure  $middleware
20 * @param  array   $options
21 * @return \Illuminate\Routing\ControllerMiddlewareOptions
22 */
23 public function middleware($middleware, array $options = []){
24    foreach ((array) $middleware as $m) {
25       $this->middleware[] = [
26          'middleware' => $m,
27          'options' => &$options,
28       ];
29    }
30    return new ControllerMiddlewareOptions($options);
31 }
```

Comment: The variable `$middleware` is of type `\Closure`, `array` or `string`.

Comment: that means you can pass middleware as string, array or a closure, example
Route::middleware('auth')  as string, Route::middleware(['auth','checkRole']) as array , Route::middleware(function(){
    return based on condition
})  as clouser